# Storing an array of samples in a database table

Tags: database, sqlite, database-schema

Every second I take 100 samples from a signal that I would like to store in a database along with some other data about the measurement.

The only way I can think of doing this is to create 100 columns to store the samples:

```
Measurement Table:                     

 -------------------------------------------------------------------
| id  |     Time  | Temp  | Sample1 | Sample2 | Sample3 ... Sample100   |
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
| 01  |  12:34:56 |  22.3 |    1    |    2    |    3    ...     4       |  
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
| 02  |  12:34:57 |  22.3 |    2    |    3    |    4    ...     5       |  
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
| 02  |  12:34:58 |  22.3 |    3    |    4    |    5    ...     6       |  
 -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This way of doing it seems sub-optimal. Is there a better way of doing it? What if I would like the option to change the number of sample at a later date?

Comment: Look into database normalization. You have a `1-0..*` relation between measurements and samples.

Answer (score 1):

Your case benefits a lot from a 1-to-N relationship. You probably need two tables:

```
create table measurement (
  id bigint primary key not null generated always as identity,
  time timestamp not null,
  temp double not null
);

create table sample (
  measurement_id bigint not null,
  sample_number int not null, -- 1, 2, 3, ... 100
  sample_value double,
  constraing fk1_sample_meas foreign key (measurement_id) 
    references measurement (id)
);
```

On `measurement` you insert only 1 row per second. On `sample` you insert 100 rows per second, related to the single measurement (column `measurement_id`).

In the future, if you need more samples per second, you can just insert more rows in `sample`. This table naturally accepts more (or less) samples per second. No structural change is needed.

*One note*: on every measurement you'll insert 101 rows (1 measurement + 100 samples). Make sure you insert them using a **transaction**. Otherwise, under system instabilities you could get incomplete measurements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry it took me so long to reply. I struggled a bit with understanding your example and comments and realized I have to refresh SQL basics.